# Can't get correct position of image inside cell relative to superview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a collection view with images inside. What I try to do is to get position of image from cell and place it in exact same place where it was when collectionView cell was tapped.

This is my initial collectionView:

[image]

This is position of image after tapped:

[image]

Code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.item != 0 {
        guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CategoryCell else { return }
        selectedImageRect = cell.image.convert(cell.image.frame, to: self.collectionView)
        selectedImage = cell.image.image!
    }
}

//////

class CategoryAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    var selectedImage: UIImage?
    var selectedImageRect: CGRect?

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 12.0
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from)!
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)!
        let finalFrameForVC = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toViewController)
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        toViewController.view.frame = finalFrameForVC.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -bounds.size.height)
        containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)

        var passedImage = UIImageView(frame: selectedImageRect!)
        passedImage.image = selectedImage!
        fromViewController.view.addSubview(passedImage)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            fromViewController.view.alpha = 0.5
            toViewController.view.frame = finalFrameForVC

        }, completion: {
            finished in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            fromViewController.view.alpha = 1.0
        })
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this :         selectedImageRect = cell.image.convert(cell.image.frame, to: self.collectionView.superview)

Comment: Try this : let theAttributes:UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes! = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
 let cellFrameInSuperview:CGRect!  = collectionView.convert(theAttributes.frame, to: collectionView.superview) **OR** selectedImageRect = cell.image.convert(cell.image.frame, to: self.collectionView.superview)

Answer (score 1):

```
    selectedImageRect = cell.convert(cell.image.frame, to: self.view)
```

That should do it